# full background image responsive internal CSS

Tags: html, css, image

I'm looking for a way to make a full background image responsive, but with internal CSS. I've tried so many other codes, but nothing seems to be working (tested in Chrome and Firefox). The breakpoints that I have are 320px, 480px, 768px, 1366px and 1920px. This is what I have in terms of code. So how exactly should I tag these media queries to give the background image for the corresponding width?  On top of that, when designing an image, what should be the appropriate height?

```html
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Naamloos document</title>
<style>

body {

  /* Location of the image */
 background-image: url(Version1/dr-muller-landing-page_1920x1080px.png);
   
  /* Image is centered vertically and horizontally at all times */
  background-position: center center;
  
  /* Image doesn't repeat */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  
  /* Makes the image fixed in the viewport so that it doesn't move when 
     the content height is greater than the image height */
  background-attachment: fixed;
  
  /* This is what makes the background image rescale based on its container's size */
  background-size: cover;
  
  /* Pick a solid background color that will be displayed while the background image is loading */
  background-color: rgb(236,146,189);
  
  /* SHORTHAND CSS NOTATION
   * background: url(background-photo.jpg) center center cover no-repeat fixed;
   */
}
  <style>
/* Three website */

* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}

.photo-grid {
 margin: 290px auto;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 max-width: 1920px;
 text-align: center;
}

.photo-grid li {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 15px;
 width: 500px;
 height: 500px;
 text-align: center;
}

.photo-grid img {
 display: block;
 max-height: 100%;
 max-width: 100%;
}

.photo-grid figure {
 height: 400px;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
 width: 400px;
}

.photo-grid figcaption {
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 color: white;
 display: table;
 height: 100%;
 left: 0;
 opacity: 0;
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 top: 0;
 z-index: 100;
}

.photo-grid figcaption p {
 display: table-cell;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 position: relative;
 top: -40px;
 width: 500px;
 vertical-align: middle;
}


.photo-grid li:hover figcaption {
 opacity: 1;
}

.photo-grid img {
 display: block;
 height: 500px;
 width: 500px;
 -webkit-transition: all 300ms;
 -moz-transition: all 300ms;
 transition: all 300ms;
 max-width: 100%;
}

.photo-grid li:hover img {
 -webkit-transform: scale(1.4);
 -moz-transform: scale(1.4);
 transform: scale(1.4);
}

.photo-grid figcaption p {
 display: table-cell;
 color: white;
 font-size: 2em;
 position: relative;
 top: -40px;
 width: 500px;
 -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
 -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
 transition: all 300ms ease-out;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

.photo-grid li:hover figcaption p {
 -moz-transform: translateY(40px);
 -webkit-transform: translateY(40px);
 transform: translateY(40px);
}


.photo-grid figcaption {
 background: rgba(192,192,192,0.3);
 color: white;
 display: table;
 height: 100%;
 left: 0;
 opacity: 0;
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 top: 0;
 -webkit-transition: all 300ms;
 -moz-transition: all 300ms;
 transition: all 300ms;
 -webkit-transition-delay: 100ms;
 -moz-transition-delay: 100ms;
 transition-delay: 100ms;
 z-index: 100;
}

@font-face {font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
src:url(fonts/ITCAvantGardeStd-Demi.otf)
}
div{font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
}
  </style>
</head>
```

Comment: Not sure to understand.. You just want to set a background image to your body, right ? Maybe you mean you don't want it to move if we scroll the page ?

Comment: And btw, could you explain what do you mean by "internal CSS" ?

Comment: @AymDev I guess he means the Internal Stylesheet.

Comment: I want a full background image that is responsive for these screens: 320px, 480px, 768px, 1366px and 1920px. But, I don't know how to tag them. I thought it would be something like this 

body {
    background-image: url (lightgreen.png);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    body {
           background-image: url (blue.png);
    }

Answer (score 1):

Try this css code:

```
html {
  background: url(images/BG.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: You don't need prefixes on `background-size`

Answer (score 0):

There is **no need to use media queries** to set a "*responsive image*".
I use to make a block for a full background (but this isn't the only way):

```
#background {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    background: url(my/image.jpeg) center center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

I write the `#background` `div`just after the `body` tag:

```
<body>
    <div id="background"></div>
    <!-- the content of the page here -->
```

---

I prefer not to use this on the `body`in case I would need to do something on it (I like to challenge myself and try things), but this is my opinion and one method to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should list your background tags after all of your Reset CSS, just to make sure the reset isn't killing any of your styles. There isn't anything conflicting but still, it is better to style after Resets. Also it looks like you have two opening style tags, and the one before the reset doesn't need to be there.